# De-serialize Array of objects to JSON in MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, morphia, nosql

I am using Morphia (ver 0.99) for my JSON to Pojo mapping to my MongoDB (ver 2.0). Streaming data between web-clients and my server works fine. But now I have a use-case where I don't know what pattern that is most appropriate. Can I use Morphia or MongoDB Java driver to achieve my requirements or do I need to use Jackson and JPA 2.2 notation.

Here is my use-case;

1. Invoke Morphia query on selected collection (MongoDB)
2. The use the resulting ArrayList of Pojos for business logic and presentation (Primefaces)
3. **Also convert the resulting ArrayList of Pojo's to JSON array of objects, but remove Pojo properties in the conversions that is not needed in the web-client**
4. Push the converted JSON to the web-client for presentation

Converting one Pojo is straight forward with Morphia, but how do I convert an array?

```
return morph.toDBObject(obj).toString();
```

Is there a notation like `@JsonIgnore` in Morphia to ignore conversions to and from JSON ?

How can I most efficiently (without using more libraries if possible) to solve step three in in my use-case. Convert ArrayList to JSON and ignore conversion of some of the Pojo properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to my problem. It's maybe not the most elegant but it works the way I want and I don't have to include other libraries (like Gson and Jackson) to de-serialize my array list of Pojo's to Json, I only used classes from the MongoDB Java driver and the Morphia API. I also added a simple parameter list to strip away unnecessary property value to be pushed to the client.

```
public static String deserializeToJSON(List<?> objList, String... removeAttributes) {
    List<DBObject> dbObjList = new ArrayList<>(objList.size());
    DBObject dbObj;
    for(Object obj :objList){
        dbObj = morph.toDBObject(obj);
        for(int i=0; i < removeAttributes.length; i++){
        debug("Removed DBObject filed: " +dbObj.removeField(removeAttributes[i]));                                    
        }
        dbObjList.add(dbObj);
    }             
    String json = JSON.serialize(dbObjList);
    return json;
}
```